# ssis sql sap hana db (odbc)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Hi I am using SSIS (MSSQL) to copy data between multiple tables. This has been working fine up until recently when the S.A.P. team keeps updating the schema of the tables without telling me.

I have multiple tables that they continue to add columns to; this in turn makes my SSIS job of copying the data across fail.

Is there a way in SSIS that I can look at the source table and adjust my destination table to reflect the changes on the fly?

I'm quite new at SSIS and don't mind running a script out of the GUI but wondered if this was an option within the GUI I'm already familiar with.

So in short, can I in SSIS allow for new columns being added to source tables and update my destination tables automatically to stop my jobs failing
 (Oh and map source to destination tables automatically)?

Comment: Short answer: no.  SSIS is static with respect to table schemas.  However, it is possible to write a SSIS Source Component that parses current schemas but always returns the same set of columns. Sounds like you need dynamic on both input and output though.

Comment: I assumed so as it was currently set up. the only problem with what your suggesting if im getting you right. I would like the extra columns, just to be notified of them and for them to map correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to include the new columns in the data flow, i.e. source and destination (include and map them). So basically you CANNOT automate what you're looking for in SSIS. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [BiML Script](http://bimlscript.com/), which lets you create and execute SSIS packages dynamically based on the meta data available at run time.

Comment: but not at runtime, which is what the OP wants IIUC

Comment: @user1443098  Yes at runtime.  BiML lets you map metadata elements to package elements.  When the "package" runs, it looks at the value of the metadata elements (like what columns are in the table now) and builds the package dynamically and runs it.

Comment: Sorry Tab, I don't think so.  BiML is a development time tool, you use it to generate packages.  Those packages are then promoted to the server environment (e.g. SSISDB, Msdb or file system) and at that time, all traces of BiML are gone.   It cannot do what you suggest because it is no longer in the picture.  Biml is a Visual Studio plugin.  No more.

Comment: @user1443098  Pardon me, I meant "BiML Script".    I often conflate them.  I will edit my answer.

Comment: That doesn't run at execution time either.  It's a (terrific!) development tool.  IIUC you're claiming that you can deploy a package to SSISDB, e.g. with BiML script embedded and that when the package is run (using  DTSEXEC) somehow BiML will do it's magic.  I wish that were true!   Alas it is not.

Comment: @user1443098  No, I'm not claiming that.  I'm claiming that you can write a program that uses BiML Script, and your job can run that program, and that program can build an SSIS package on the fly based on the meta data at runtime, and then execute it and destroy it.  And it can do this repeatedly on a schedule.

Comment: Interesting, Wouldn't you need to install BiML on the server?  I'd have a tough time getting that approved in my shop.  It may be easier to just code the program to do what you want in the first place, forget about SSIS and BiML.